# Redirect to custom view in case overall page takes more than 30 seconds in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a MVC view which is rendering multiple partial views and two action. In this scenario sometime we face page unresponsiveness issue. 
So Can I implement any action filters type solution based on overall performance of View?

Basically I want to redirect to a custom page whenever this view takes more than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If U R using **web.config** file for setting idle timeout for each page

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="20" mode="InProc" />
.....

<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="20" />
    </authentication>
```

this above setting are know as server-side setting and redirecting page after 20min to perticular page.

OR

U Can use the client-side scripting for the same.Use following javascript code that you could run on every page load.

```
SetTimeout(function()
{
window.location.href = "/"; // U can use @Url.Content("~/") inside the quotes to also or else give the page path  to the page U want to redirect 
}, 10 * 60 * 1000); // 10 mins * 60 sec/min * 1000 ms/sec. (set U R won timeout)
```

This code would redirect someone to the homepage after 10 minutes of idle on a page or take longer time to load the content.

Comment: thanks. I will give it a try and update if it works for me.